# Парсинг XML с двоеточиями в тэгах

Tags: javascript, xml, парсер

Добрый день.

Я написал скрипт, который обращается к стороннему сервису, отсылая xml и получая другой xml в ответ.

После этого мне нужно из полученного xml выдернуть значения некоторых тэгов.

Я делаю это так:

```
var result = response.getElementsByTagName('serv:result')[0].innerHTML
```

Проблема в том, что некоторые браузеры не ищут по тегам, внутри которых есть двоеточие, для них нужно писать просто "result" вместо "serv:result". А другие браузеры наоборот - ищут только по полному названию с двоеточием.

Я уже нагуглил, что двоеточие в теге относится к такому понятию, как "пространства имён xml". Но по этим словам гугль выдаёт огромные объёмы общей информации, а мне нужно решить всего один конкретный вопрос.

Есть ли в JS способ нормально искать по xml-тегам с двоеточием?

Comment: Разные браузеры и правда xml обрабатывают по-разному. Я бы  перевел xml в текст, и использовать regeх и split что б получить нужную информацию. (Не раз так делал)

Comment: Второй способ, можно написать вот так `(response.getElementsByTagName('serv:result') | response.getElementsByTagName('serv') )[0].innerHTML`  не найдено 1-м способом - пусть ищет вторым.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё, нагуглил.

Есть специальная функция getElementsByTagNameNS().
Работает так:

```
response.getElementsByTagNameNS(NamespaceURI, "result")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

При этом значения NamespaceURI прописаны в начале самой ответной xml.